# 'How do i prove that this point y$_0$ $\in$ $f(A)$ using this statements?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, compactness

i have been struggling with this problem since two days before, let´s see:

> Let $f: A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ that if $V=V°$ then
> $A\setminus f^{-1}(V)=A\cap W$ for some $W\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ that $W=\overline{W}$. If $A$ is compact it follows that: if $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ a sequence in $f(A)$ which converges to $y_0$ then $y_0\in f(A)$.

My first attempt consisted in trying to prove that since *A* is compact then is closed $A\cap W$ is closed, more over $A\setminus f^{-1}(V)$ is closed, I want $f^{-1}(V)$ to be open, so $f$ is continuous, then $f$ map compact sets to compact sets, and problem solved. But I couldn't manage to prove that.

The other thing that I tried was using the fact that if $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ a sequence in $f(A)$ convergent to $y_0$ then $y_0 \in \overline{f(A)}$. In this case I think that I need to prove that $f(A)$ is closed but I got stuck.

Comment: $A \setminus f^{-1}(V)$ is closed implies $f^{-1}(V)$ is open with respect to the subspace topology of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the right idea.
The statement "$V = V^0$ then $A\backslash f^{-1}(V) = A\cap W$ for $W$ such that $W = \bar{W}$" is the same as saying that the preimage by $f$ of any open set in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is open in $A$, which is indeed the same as saying that $f$ is continuous.

You could indeed use the fact that the image of compact sets by a continuous function is compact, but if you haven't proven it, that result needs to be proven (is that the part you are stuck on? Or have you already done that?) But even after that, you need one last step to prove the desired result.

*Hint:* do you know what characterizes a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: Oh, ok I see, i still have a doubt about how the first statement implied that $f$ was continious, i have to say that i can´t stablish the equivalence. I have already prove that, the part were i was stuck was in fact just the equivalence of the statements cause there is a result that it says "if *X* $\subseteq$ *A* open then *A*\$f^{-1}(V)$  is closed" but not the reciprocal. And as far i can see i need to show that is sequencially compact to end the prove, am I right? Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: The first statement is the topological definition of continuity (the pre-image of an open set by the function is open). So, since $A$ is compact, $f(A)$ is compact by continuity of $f$. Now, what you are trying to prove is that every converging sequence in $f(A)$ has its limit $f(A)$. This is not sequential compactness, it is closedness. :)

Comment: Because sequential compactness deals with limit points, it is a different statement. ($B$ is sequentially compact if every sequence in $B$ has a subsequence that converges in $B$, this is not the same)

Answer (score 0):

If $V=V^\circ$ (i.e. $V$ is open) then $f^{-1}[V]$ is open in $A$ by continity of $f$ and so $A\setminus f^{-1}[V]$ is closed in $A$ (complement (within $A$) of an open set) and this means (by the definition of subspace topology) that it equals $A \cap W$ with $W$ closed (or $\overline{W}=W$). That explains the first sentence. Then presumably $A$ is compact, so $f[A]$ is compact as the continuous image of $A$ (and thus $f[A]$ is closed) and then the statement about the sequence is a standard consequence of being closed (a sequence from the set that converges only has a limit in that same set).